# Merge two dataframes with special order

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two df:

```
Type   price   stock
a      2       2
a      4       1
a      3       3


Type   price   stock
b      1       1
b      2       4
c      3       2
c      4       1
c      5       3
c      5       3
b      2       4
```

I would like to merge these two df, the resulting df I would like to get is

```
Type   price*stock
b      1       1
b      2       4
a      2       2
c      3       2
c      4       1
a      4       1
c      5       3
c      5       3
a      3       3
b      2       4
```

From top, you could see I would like to insert the first df into the second the df, the logic is two rows from the second df, and then one row from the first df.

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
df2.index = df2.index//2
out = df2.append(df1).sort_index()
Out[42]: 
  Type  price  stock
0    b      1      1
0    b      2      4
0    a      2      2
1    c      3      2
1    c      4      1
1    a      4      1
2    c      5      3
2    c      5      3
2    a      3      3
3    b      2      4
```